# Rotate text 90 degrees and vertically center next to wrapped inline text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to rotate text 90 degrees and vertically center it next to inline wrapped text. I need to keep the text inline so I can left-align the text itself, then center the whole thing when the text wraps.

It seems to work fine in Chrome when the text is on one line and when wrapped. In Firefox it seems to work fine when the text is on one line, but when wrapped, it does not vertically center the rotated text.

It seems like Firefox is not recognizing the height of the wrapped text.

Here is a fiddle showing what I'm working with. https://jsfiddle.net/hemmieweizen/7t5gh91z/12/ Notice on Firefox when you decrease the width of the output and the text wraps, the vertical text does not continue to center.

```css
.title-container {
    font-size: 70px;
    position: relative;
}
.title-container .title {
    position: relative;
}
.title-container .pre-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 50%;
    left: -55px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    height: 22px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="title-container m-b-0">
  <span class="title">
    <span class="pre-title h6 m-b-0">Your Agent</span>
      Charles Smith
    </span>
</h2>
```

Comment: Deleted my answer because I ended up basically in the same situation. Seems to be an issue with FireFox and inline elements, position absolute only considers the height of the first line... very weird

Comment: Have you tried using `writing-mode: vertical-lr`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a layout like `flex`; make both `<span>Charles Smith</span>` and `<span>Your Agent</span>` direct children of `<h2>` rather than nested children. Remove the hard-coded `position` rules from these elements, and let the flexbox manage them for you. You can still refine their positions with mere `margin` and `padding`.

```css
@import url("https://d133rs42u5tbg.cloudfront.net/hero/assets/css/kv-custom-colors.css");
.title-container {
  font-size: 70px;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;         /* ADDED THIS NEW RULE */
  flex-direction: row;   /* ADDED THIS NEW RULE */
}

.title-container .pre-title { /* DID NOT CHANGE ANYTHING HERE */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: -55px;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  height: 22px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.title-container .title {
    /* REMOVED OLD POSITION RULE */
}
```

```html
<section id="custom-about" class="position-relative p-y-3">
  <div class="container p-y-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
        <h2 class="title-container m-b-0">

          <!-- CHANGED HIERARCHICAL STRUCTURE HERE -->

          <span class="pre-title h6 font-sans m-b-0">Your Agent</span>
          <span class="title">Charles Smith</span>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 m-t-2">
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
          in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-md-offset-6">
        <div class="text-center">
          <a class="btn btn-white" href="contact">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: This is very similar to my first approach but it doesn't allow for centering the heading.